# pseudo classes -animation with css3

Tags: animation, css

I am trying this [demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/index10.html):

In my case i have a group of buttons. When the user press a specific button, a scroll to position is made to a specific box.
Well the problem is that the cursor sometimes stays above the incorrect box. So the effect hover is made in the wrong box. To avoid this, i think the best option is change the `:hover` to something like `onClick` (js).

With `:active` the effect sounds a bit strange, the user need to pressing continuously the image.

There is other option with css ? maybe, some hack ? the action should be identically to `onClick` (js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make you can use `:target` pseudo property for this. Check this for more http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:target